# Xcode Can't Debug View Frame

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, uivisualeffectview

I can't use the debug View feather in Xcode 
when I use Debug Menu > View Debugging > Show View Frames
there is an Assertion log in the console.

```
Assertion failure in -[UIVisualEffectView _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:], 
/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKitCore/UIKit-3698.94.10/UIVisualEffectView.m:1859
```

With any project and with Development SDK 10, 11, 12
and I tried to delete the Xcode and reinstall it 
with Xcode 10 and 10.1 as I remember 
[image]
[image]

It work fine if create a new project with one view Controller . But once embedded it in navigation controller it stoped working , 
I think the isTranslucent is Using UIVisualEffect  witch failed in the Assertion .

Is there a work around this Issues , or it is known for apple?

Answer (score 0):

It's likely a bug in `iOS`.When click `View Debug` -> `Show View Frames`, `UIView` add `_UIDebugColorBoundsView` `_UIDebugAlignmentRectView` as subView, while `UIVisualEffectView` is kind of `UIView`.So When `View Debug`, `UIVisualEffectView`  will add some `_UIDebugXXXViews` as subView, **BUT** **[Do not add subviews directly to the visual effect view itself.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uivisualeffectview)**,which will result in crash. We should add any subviews to the contentView property of the visual effect view.to fix this, need some hack with objc runtime as below:

```objectivec
#import <objc/runtime.h>

#if DEBUG
@implementation UIView (Debug)

+ (void)load {
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        SEL systemSel       = @selector(addSubview:);
        SEL swizzSel        = @selector(dy_degbugAddSubview:);
        Method systemMethod = class_getInstanceMethod([self class], systemSel);
        Method swizzMethod  = class_getInstanceMethod([self class], swizzSel);
        BOOL isAdd = class_addMethod(self, systemSel, method_getImplementation(swizzMethod),
            method_getTypeEncoding(swizzMethod));
        if (isAdd) {
            class_replaceMethod(self, swizzSel, method_getImplementation(systemMethod),
                method_getTypeEncoding(systemMethod));
        } else {
            method_exchangeImplementations(systemMethod, swizzMethod);
        }
    });
}

- (void)dy_degbugAddSubview:(UIView *)view {
    if ([self isKindOfClass:[UIVisualEffectView class]]) {
        // _UIDebugColorBoundsView
        // _UIDebugAlignmentRectView
        if ([[[view class] description] containsString:@"_UIDebug"]) {
            // View DEBUG will assert failure
            [[(UIVisualEffectView *)self contentView] dy_degbugAddSubview:view];
            return;
        }
        [self dy_degbugAddSubview:view];
    } else {
        [self dy_degbugAddSubview:view];
    }
}
@end

#endif
```